# Fraud Detection ML Logistic Regression model getting 1.00 scores?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I have just started learning ML concepts and I was working on a personal project about fraud detection using ML.

The dataset is a very large sum of transaction data with various data types. So I need to create a Logistic Regression model, and I did, but whenever I get to the scoring of train & test models, I receive a score of 1.00 on both. What is going on here ?

I needed to get around the fact that 3 of my columns are string-type so to convert them to numeric values I tried some things but I probably messed up. All insights are appreciated.

CODE :

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

transaction_data = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/train.csv")

# first 5 rows

transaction_data.head()
```

[first 5 rows of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5GU8.png)

```
transaction_data.info()
```

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2372805 entries, 0 to 2372804
Data columns (total 12 columns):
    Column          Dtype  
---  ------          -----  
 0   Id              int64  
 1   step            int64  
 2   action          object 
 3   amount          float64
 4   nameOrig        object 
 5   oldBalanceOrig  float64
 6   newBalanceOrig  float64
 7   nameDest        object 
 8   oldBalanceDest  float64
 9   newBalanceDest  float64
 10  isFraud         int64  
 11  isFlaggedFraud  int64  
dtypes: float64(5), int64(4), object(3)
memory usage: 217.2+ MB
```

```
# distribution of fraud & fraud transactions

transaction_data["isFraud"].value_counts()
```

```
0    2372627
1        178
Name: isFraud, dtype: int64
```

```
# fitting action and orig&dest columns

action_ec = LabelEncoder()
action_ec.fit(transaction_data["action"])

names = pd.concat([transaction_data["nameOrig"], transaction_data["nameDest"]], axis=0)
name_ec = LabelEncoder()
name_ec.fit(names)
```

```
# converting columns to numeric values

transaction_data["action"] = action_ec.transform(transaction_data["action"])

transaction_data["nameOrig"] = name_ec.transform(transaction_data["nameOrig"])
transaction_data["nameDest"] = name_ec.transform(transaction_data["nameDest"])
```

```
# first 5 rows

transaction_data.head()
```

[new table where strings converted to numeric values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lj3km.png)

```
# seperating for analysis

legit = transaction_data[transaction_data.isFraud == 0]
legit_X = legit.drop(columns="isFraud", axis=1)
legit_Y = legit["isFraud"]

fraud = transaction_data[transaction_data.isFraud == 1]
fraud_X = fraud.drop(columns="isFraud", axis=1)
fraud_Y = fraud["isFraud"]
```

```
"""
Splitting data into training data and testing data
"""

legit_X_train, legit_X_test, legit_Y_train, legit_Y_test = train_test_split(legit_X, legit_Y, test_size=0.2)
fraud_X_train, fraud_X_test, fraud_Y_train, fraud_Y_test = train_test_split(fraud_X, fraud_Y, test_size=0.2)

X_train = shuffle(pd.concat([legit_X_train, fraud_X_train], axis=0))
Y_train = shuffle(pd.concat([legit_Y_train, fraud_Y_train], axis=0))
X_test = shuffle(pd.concat([legit_X_test, fraud_X_test], axis=0))
Y_test = shuffle(pd.concat([legit_Y_test, fraud_Y_test], axis=0))
```

```
"""
Model Training
Logistic Regression
"""

model = LogisticRegression(solver="lbfgs", max_iter=3000)

model.fit(X_train, Y_train)

print("model score test: %.3f" % model.score(X_test, Y_test))
print("model score training: %.3f" % model.score(X_train, Y_train))
```

```
model score test: 1.000
model score training: 1.000
```

Comment: UNPOSSIBLE. Either you must be having data with only one label in train test, or there must be data leakage from train to test.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to imbalancing data of your label since we have 99.95% of labels with 0, so your model is predicting 0 most of the time which it's explain that you have 100% prediction score.

What I can suggest to your is use some balancing techniques like **SMOTE** [Smote example on python](https://machinelearningmastery.com/smote-oversampling-for-imbalanced-classification/)

Comment: Indeed, predicting always 0 would give (on the whole dataset, I don't have access to the test split) accuracy of 1-178/2372627=0.99992... which rounds to 1.000 with the precision requested in OP's code.

Comment: That said, I disagree that SMOTE is the first tool to reach for here.  Choosing a decision threshold other than the default of 0.5, and/or using a better metric than the default of `accuracy` in `model.score`, would be my first picks.

Comment: yeah I totally agree with you,  but it can be one of the approaches to use in this problem he can test using other metrics or using smote or seing another methods.